# CKEditor allow all content except font-size, line-height, uppercase

Tags: filter, ckeditor

Is there a config option in CKEditor to allow all content except certain styles (font-size, line-height, uppercase,....).

Is that possible? I checked ACF but I didn't see that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disallowed Content](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disallowedContent) is what you are looking for. See more here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content-section-how-to-allow-everything-except...